# SED: extract from google finance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed, currency, conky

my code:

```
${execi 3600 wget -q -O - "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=PLN"|grep "<div id=currency_converter_result>"|sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'}
```

i trying to get currency rate from google finances:

https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=PLN

result its:

```
1 PLN = 3.0321  USD
```

how i can mod my code to get result:

```
USD 3.03
```

Thanks!

Comment: The query you have used in the question returns "1 USD = 3.0316 PLN" for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```
wget -q -O - "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=PLN"|awk -F"[ >]" '/<div id=currency_converter_result>/ {printf "%s %.2f\n",$4,$8}'
USD 3.03
```

To get it into an variable:

```
val=$(wget -q -O - "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=PLN"|awk -F"[ >]" '/<div id=currency_converter_result>/ {printf "%s %.2f\n",$4,$8}')
echo "$val"
USD 3.03
```